# How to detect the colour of the specific pixel the mouse curser is directly on (for any place on the screen)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

I am trying to automate some work using python code and the function "pyautogui" but I need to find a way to detect colours where the mouse is on the screen.
Anyone has any solutions?
Thanking in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code attempted?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    px = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    print(px)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pyautogui.pixel(x, y)` to obtain the `(red, green, blue)` value of the pixel where the mouse is. On macOS unfortunately, the mouse cursor itself is included in the screenshot. You will have to call `x, y = pyautogui.position()` to obtain the x, y coordinates, then call `pyautogui.moveRel(50, 0)` to move the mouse cursor away, then call `pyautogui.pixel(x, y)` to get the color of the pixel of where the mouse cursor was.

This will hopefully be corrected on macOS in a future version of PyAutoGUI.